# $uibModal inject resolved item into another resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i am using $uibModal in a factory, i want to chain the resolves but i am getting a provider error for `post`.

```
return {
openTextEditModal: function(id) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
        backdrop: 'static',
        controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance, $sce, post, user, $http, $stateParams) {},
        size: 'lg',
        resolve: {             
            post: function() {
                return $q.when('testing');
            },
            user:function(post){
               //do stuff with post   

               return $q.when(userObj);
            },
        }
    });
},
close:function(){
    $uibModal.close();
}
```

};

how can i use a resolved value in the followig resolves? (chaining resolves).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like this. However, you can chain promises in one resolve block:

```
resolve: {
    user: function() {
        return $q.when('testing')
            .then(function(post) {
                //do stuff with post   
                return $q.when(userObj);        
            });
    },
}
```